# PHP and MySQL Display by date and time

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a way to display my upcoming events by the date they are with out displaying any past events.

MySQL Table:

```
ID   |   Title   |   Date   |   Time
1        title1    2013-10-5    12:00
2        title2   2013-10-10    12:00
3        title3   2013-10-25    01:00
4        title4   2013-10-31    11:30
```

I would like it to display like so:

```
title2 2013-10-10
title3 2013-10-24
title4 2013-10-31
```

without it displaying any events that have passed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use separate `DATE` and `TIME` fields instead of a single `DATETIME`?

Comment: WHYT - What Have You Tried? We are here to help you fix errors or give a new angle on problems, not solving everything for you.

Comment: Try `diff` http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: People here aren't going to spell out an answer since you haven't posted what you've tried, but you should try to do this in the query itself, not with a PHP function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html. You'll want to check that the date isn't before today's date and the time isn't before the current time...

Comment: @TheWolf - I don't know, I just do.

Comment: @OptimusCrime - I wasn't sure how to go about this. I'll be sure to try before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your current structure, you could use `CURDATE()` and `CURTIME()`

```
SELECT
  id, title, date, time
FROM
  titles
WHERE
  date >= CURDATE() AND time >= CURTIME()
```

Read up on  [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Works prefect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you store date and time together in a `DATETIME` field. You can then use:

```
SELECT title, DATE(`datetime`) AS `date`
FROM table
WHERE `datetime` >= NOW()
```

(See [DATE and TIME functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html))